# Obtener la posición y el valor del segundo mayor elemento de una lista

Tags: python, array

Tengo un problema con Python y es que teniendo una lista como esta:

```
v = [2,1,9,3,6,4,5,10,8,7]
```

quiero coger el número más alto, el 10, para luego poder coger los números que fuesen menores a este. Es decir, del 1 al 9 y después coger de este nuevo vector el número más alto, es decir el 9 y saber en que posición está. De esta forma cogería la posición del segundo valor más alto.

Esto es lo que haría para obtener el valor:

```
>>> numbers = [2,1,9,3,6,4,5,10,8,7]
>>> sorted(numbers)[-2]
```

Pero no se que hacer para obtener la posición también.

Comment: Hola Fran, primero de todo ¿qué es lo que llamas "vector"?  ¿Estamos hablando de una lista, de una tupla, de un set, de un array de NumPy...? Por otro lado te sugiero que agregues lo que has intentado o mírate la función preconstruida `sorted`. Un saludo.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo modifico para que se vea mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `enumerate` junto a `sorted` tal y como lo usas tu para obtener el valor junto a su índice. Simplemente debemos ordenar por el segundo valor de las tuplas `(indice, valor)` retornadas por `enumerate`, para ello podemos usar `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> numbers=[2,1,9,3,6,4,5,10,8,7]
>>> numbers_sort = sorted(enumerate(numbers), key=itemgetter(1),  reverse=True)
>>> index, value = numbers_sort[1]
>>> print("Segundo valor más alto: {}, índice:{}".format(value, index))
Segundo valor más alto: 9, índice:2
```

**Edición:**

Si no se puede o quiere usar `operator.itemgetter` para el argumento `key` se puede usar una expresión lambda. `itemgetter` es más eficiente que usar expresiones lambda ya que trabaja a nivel de C evitando la sobrecarga ocasionada al llamar a funciones Python puras pero obtenemos el mismo resultado:

```
>>> numbers=[2,1,9,3,6,4,5,10,8,7]
>>> numbers_sort = sorted(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda x: x[1],  reverse=True)
>>> print("Segundo valor más alto: {1}, índice:{0}".format(*numbers_sort[1]))
Segundo valor más alto: 9, índice:2
```

Usando **NumPy** podemos obtener el mismo resultado usando `numpy.arrsort` que nos retorna un array con los índices de los elementos ordenados:

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array([2,1,9,3,6,4,5,10,8,7])
idx = n.argsort()[-2]
res = np.array((idx, n[idx]))
```

Comment: Si suponemos que en el programa no me deja importar operator como se haría. ¿Lo sabes?. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Usa una función lambda, es algo menos eficiente pero funciona igual. Espera que edito la respuesta.

Comment: Si puedes o sabes podrías decirme como hacerlo con numpy.where y que se me quede como un float el resultado.

Comment: @FranAhedoGuerrero ¿solo quieres obtener el segundo valor o tienes intención de iterar sobre el array ordenado o de obtener el resto de los valores con posterioridad? ¿Para el array del ejemplo que salida deseas, con numpy?¿Un array 2d con las parejas indice-valor ordenadas o solo el indice y valor del segundo mayor?

Comment: Un array 2d con solo el indice y valor del segundo mayor, perdón es que soy un poco novato con python y estoy traduciendo desde R y es un poco diferente.

Comment: Quiero que con el where me de la posición.

Comment: ¿Es imprescindible usar  `where`?, creo que hay opciones más simples para obtener la pareja.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64867/discussion-between-fran-ahedo-guerrero-and-fjsevilla).